# Reconstruct corrupted Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, file-recovery

I accidentally broke an MS Word file with a bunch of comments in it. I tried the usual recovery methods but the only thing that remotely worked as opening it in `Recover Text` mode, which gave me the whole doc, including comments, but it looks like this:

> \par \hich\af0\dbch\af31505\loch\f0 Ben Snell\hich\f0 \rquote \loch\f0
>   s AI-driven work is by no means unique in flashing the
>   compl\hich\af0\dbch\af31505\loch\f0
>
> ications and difficult questions that arise at the intersection of art
>   and emerging computational technology. Indeed, much contemporary art
>   that draws on machine learning (ML) and artificial intelligence
>   \hich\f0 \endash \loch\f0
>
> what is now broadly categorised as \hich\f0 \lquote \loch\f0 AI
>   art\hich\f0 \rquote \loch\f0  \hich\f0 \endash \loch\f0  {*\atrfstart
>   574363154}str\hich\af0\dbch\af31505\loch\f0
>   u\hich\af0\dbch\af31505\loch\f0 ggles}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs16
>   \ltrch\fcs0
>
> \cs17\fs16\insrsid13959592 {*\atrfend 574363154}{*\atnid
>   JT}{*\atnauthor Jeff Thompson}\chatn {*\annotation{*\atnref
>   574363154}{*\atndate -947627382}\ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar

Is there a tool/process to reconstruct the original document from this? It seems to all be there and some of the formatting makes sense (`annotation` for comments, characters like `\rquote`) but not enough that it's actually human-readable.

A few details:

- I'm on Mac (Mojave)
- The file was `.doc` not `.docx`
- I did try finding the auto recovery file (no luck) and using an unzip utility to extract the XML (didn't find anything)
- Also tried loading it into Google Docs – the original file opens great and looks normal but no comments are visible
- I'm weirded out by most of the online recovery tools

Comment: Try opening the document in LibreOffice Word, which might be able to salvage it... or not.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik – thanks for the suggestion, doesn't seem to work though :(

Comment: At the very least to be recognised as RTF your text would need  "{\\rtf1\\ansi" at the beginning (there should only be two single backslashes in there) and "}" at the end, but getting RTF to work usually means 'going through and matching up the "{" and "}" brackets' manually.